# Using react2angular, react isn't recognized, no erros

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

I am transitioning an angularjs project to react.  For this I'm using react2angular.  I've followed the tutorials, but for some reason, react isn't recognized.  I'm not receiving any errors.  Note: I've also tried ngReact and had the same problem.

I have a very simple react component: 
**MyComponent.jsx**

```
import { Component } from 'react'
import { react2angular } from 'react2angular'

class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log('MyComponent Render');
    return <div>
      <p>FooBar: {this.props.fooBar}</p>
      <p>Baz: {this.props.baz}</p>
    </div>
  }
}

angular
    .module('deuiApp', [])
    .component('myComponent', react2angular(MyComponent, ['fooBar', 'baz']));
```

I added the component to:
**text.tpl.html**

```
<div>
  <div class="QuestText">
    <my-component foo-bar="3" baz="'baz'"></my-component>
  </div>
</div>
```

When it's running and I inspect the html page in Chrome's Developer Tools, I see this.

```
<div class="QuestText">
  <my-component foo-bar="3" baz="'baz'"></my-component>
</div
```

Nothing shows up in the console.  It's as if it doesn't even recognize react.

**More Information:**

In **package.json**  -- *npm packages are installed*

```
dependencies: {
    "angular": "1.6.10",
    "angular-cookies": "1.6.10",
    "angular-i18n": "1.6.10",
    "angular-resource": "1.6.10",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.6.10",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "0.32.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react2angular": "^4.0.6",
},
devDependencies: {
    "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "6.24.1",
    "webpack": "3.11.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.11.2",
}
```

Relevant information in **webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = function () {
  const config = {};

  config.resolve = {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.css', '.scss']
  };
  config.devtool = 'source-map'
  config.module = {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: ['ng-annotate-loader', {
          loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
          options: {
            entryFileIsJs: true,
            transpileOnly: true
           }
        }],
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
      }]
  }

 return config;
}();
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx"],
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "modules": false,
      "targets": {
        "node": "current",
        "browsers": [
          "chrome >= 59",
          "firefox >= 50",
          "ie >= 11",
          "edge >= 40"
        ]
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

I'm at a loss.  I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Use `my-component` ... all lowercase.

Comment: @georgeawg It still won't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are missing the right injection way, because in the documentation of react2angular it says

> Dependency Injection It's easy to pass services/constants/etc. to your
>   React component: just pass them in **as the 3rd argument**, and they will
>   be available in your component's Props. For example:

```
angular
  .module('myModule', [])
  .constant('FOO', 'FOO!')
  .component('myComponent', react2angular(MyComponent, [], ['$http', 'FOO']))
```

your code must be in this order

```
angular
    .module('deuiApp', [])
    .component('myComponent', react2angular(MyComponent, [], ['fooBar', 'baz']));
```

Comment: according to documentation 3rd parameters are dependencies and 2nd parameter are props, which the author is trying to pass

Comment: @Sergii go to https://github.com/coatue-oss/react2angular and read this lines: .component('myComponent', react2angular(MyComponent, [], ['$http', 'FOO']))

Comment: the syntax is react2angular(component, props, deps) - what are you trying to achieve with the previous comment?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're not bootstrapping angular, unless you're doing it somewhere else; you haven't posted the bootstrapping code.

Bootstrapping is either done with an [ngApp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) directive:

```html
<body ng-app="deuiApp">
```

or manually:

```
angular.bootstrap(document.createElement('div'), ['deuiApp']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
import { Component } from 'react'
```

use:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
```